# check if random number is equal to a specific number. java

Tags: java, for-loop, random, numbers

Building a program that can check if a random number is = to a specific number. Here is what I have so far. I am generating a random number 10 times. And I want it to print out "The number (int var) was found (How ever many times it generated) times.".   I keep running into problems such as trying to pull static variable from non-static variable. I'm not sure how to check if the integer is = to the random number.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Driver{


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

         Loop.loop4(4);
    }
```

---

```
public class Loop
{

    public static void loop4(int val)
    {

        for(int iteration = 1; iteration <=10; iteration ++)
        {
            Random number = new Random(); 
            number.nextInt(10);
        }

        System.out.println("The number " + val +" was found " (Dont know how to do this part);
    }


}
```

Comment: Your print statement is outside of the method!

Comment: You need to compare ```number``` with ```val```, and everytime the 2 are equal, you need to increment a local counter, which you can then print.

Comment: Whoops! fixed. Thanks

Comment: Thats what I was thinking @Siddhartha. I will keep messing with that idea. thanks.

Comment: Let us know if you get stuck

Comment: The problem I'm having is that I can't compare a random number with an integer. Do i convert it somehow?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong actually. You don't compare ```number``` to ```val```, you compare ```number.nextInt(10);``` to it, which you'll need to store in a variable. Or you can do the comparison directly - ```(val == number.nextInt(10))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like:

```
int count = 0;
for(int iteration = 1; iteration <=10; iteration ++) {
   Random number = new Random(); 
   int n = number.nextInt(10);
   if(n == val) count++;
}
System.out.println("The number " + val +" was found " + count + "  number of times");
```

Just compare `val` with the random number generated and see if they are `equal` in the `if() {...}`, keep a `counter` to keep track of how many times the random number was equal to `val`.

Comment: YAY, I've never used a nested loop(Guess maybe its not a nested loop) yet in Java I'm new :P. It makes sense though now that I can see it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@thegauravmahawar 's answer seems decent and interesting.

Nonetheless, here's a suggestion on how to enhance your code:

(Don't mind if it's got any minor errors; I wrote it all on nano)

```
package loop;

import java.util.Random;

public class Loop {

public static void main(String[] args){

int number = 100, range = 100 // Type in any ints

if looper(number, range) { System.out.println("Number %i found!", number) }
else { System.out.println("Number not found!" ) }

}


public bool looper(int numberToBeFound, int range){

guard numberToBeFound<=range else { System.out.println("number to be found is
greater than range!") }

for (int i = 1; i<=range; i++) {

Random randomNumber = new Random();
randomNumber.nextInt(range)

if randomNumber == NumberToBeFound { break; return true } // Unsure if this'll work

}

return false

}

}
```

Comment: Wow yeah I am not that good at programming yet, but I will definitely keep this answer in my archives for later! ;)

Comment: The purpose of the looper() function is to stop as soon as a random value corresponding to the desired number is found, returning true, or return false if it doesn't happen.

If you want, you could create another looper()-like function that returns an int, and let it return a counter of how many times said value was found.

Just be sure to check if the int is 0 or something else!

Comment: By the way, you should try putting functions related to that class inside that class. I saw no purpose on creating a new class just to call a single function/method; that's why I implemented the looping function inside of the main class.

Comment: You can also add any variable you have inside a string by utilizing something called 'String Interpolation', like I did up there (at "Number %i found!"). May help you make cleaner, less exhausting code.